Reference for a proof on homotopy groups of simplicial abelian groups
In Simplicial Homotopy Theory, Goerss and Jardine wrote : 
The simplicial abelian group structure on A induces an abelian group structure
on the set $\pi_n$(A, 0) = [($\Delta^n$, $\partial \Delta^n$), (A, 0)] of homotopy classes of pairs of maps which satisfies an interchange law with respect to the canonical group structure for the homotopy group. 
But they don't prove it. Does someone has a reference containing a proof of this statement please ? I searched but I wasn't be able to find it.

Have you tried using the Eckman-Hilton argument?

The Eckman-Hilton argument is an argument to show that 2 operations that satisfy an interchange law are in fact equal.
Me, I'm looking for a proof that the 2 operations on the homotopy groups of a simplicial abelian group verify this interchange law. And the canonical group structure on the homotopy groups of a Kan complex is not clear for me, so I don't know how to prove this fact.

Let $\alpha\colon A\times A\to A$ denote the addition map. This is a map of simplicial sets, hence the composite $$\pi_n(A)\times\pi_n(A)\cong \pi_n(A\times A)\xrightarrow{\pi_n(\alpha)}\pi_n(A),$$
which we denote by $\beta$, is a group homomorphism.
It follows that the equality $$\beta((a+b),(c+d)) = \beta((a,c)+(b,d)) = \beta(a,c) + \beta(b,d)$$
holds and this is exactly the interchange law of the Eckman-Hilton argument. Note that it is not essential for $A$ to be abelian.

Thank you ! It was exactly what I wanted.
